# zsh: No such widget `End'

Tags: zsh

Suppose I want to create a directory with the `aka` letter combination in it, e.g., `leakage` or `Dakar`. When I start typing the first one in, everything is fine until I get to `mkdir le`. Right after that, while I type the `aka` part, it does not show on screen - instead, a

```
No such widget `End'
```

appears on the next terminal line (without the usual `zsh` prompt). The `aka` part is still not showing, and when I finally type in the rest, `ge`, this is what I end up with:

```
login@server folderName % mkdir lege
No such widget `End'
```

The same is with the `Dakar`:

```
login@server folderName % mkdir Dr
No such widget `End'
```

I noticed that if I type slowly (at about 1 symbol per second), everything is just fine. But when it's just a little bit faster, I get into the above-mentioned trouble. What is this?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out:

For years, I had the following in my `~/.zshrc`:

```
bindkey '\e[4~' end-of-line             aka End
```

instead of

```
bindkey '\e[4~' end-of-line             # aka End
```

Interesting that it has never given me troubles until now.